# Dreamhost and pyramid output logging

Tags: apache, logging, passenger, pyramid, dreamhost

How do I log the sdtout from my pyramid application hosted on dreamhost to file?  Can I have 3 log files, one for Pyramid, Passenger and Apache each?

Is it possible to do this from the production.ini file?

I'm still quite a noob, so would you please be explicit?

Comment: Do you run a VPS at dreamhost or do you somehow run Pyramid on their Shared hosting?

Comment: I think its a VPS.  I am unfortunately a bit new at all of this

Comment: [Configuring logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) section of manual would be helpful for you